# Вернуть значения в массиве

Tags: sql, postgresql

для примера, в школе есть классы, в классах ученики.
При выводе

```
select class, name from scholl

class   name
1a      Петя
1a      Ваня
1а      Алеша
1b      Сережа
```

В ответе мы получим столько строк сколько учеников в школе, можно ли как-то вернуть значения name в массиве?

```
class   name
1a      {Петя, Ваня, Сережа, Алеша}
1b      Сережа
```

Comment: можно в одном поле через запятую, а в массив превратите сами.

Comment: @Mike ок, а как вывести в одно поле через запятую?

Comment: Хотя вроде есть и массив, правда не знаю как оно на клиента придет. `select class, array_agg(name) from table group by class` попробуйте

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Все отработало как надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В postgresql (с версии 9) выборка значений в виде массива выглядит так:

```
select class, array_agg(name)
  from table
 group by class
```