# INNER JOIN слияние нескольких строк

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть следующая проблема:

Нужно получить данные так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а они получаются вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тута код - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cd35a18a2267c03adffcbe1f8948e6da

Как быть, что делать?

**Добавлено**

Я придумал сделать так... но как это прикрутить, что бы значения подставлялись, не знаю... (мне кажется, что это сомнительный вариант)

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, array_to_string(array((
    SELECT users_skills.id_skill
    FROM users_skills
    WHERE users_skills.id_user = users.id
)), ', ') AS skill
FROM users;
```

**Добавлено 2**

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, array_to_string(array_agg(skills.skill), ', ')
FROM users
INNER JOIN users_skills ON (users.id = users_skills.id_user)
INNER JOIN skills ON (users_skills.id_skill = skills.id)
GROUP BY users.id;
```

Comment: GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: @Akina а можно пример?)

Comment: Пардон, в Постгрессе это GROUP BY + ARRAY_AGG(). *а можно пример?* https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491342/229437

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вернуть значения в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491333/%d0%92%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Comment: @Akina Я отредактировал вопрос, и вставил код, который правильно выводит данные. Вопрос: если вдруг такое решение будет использоваться на боевом проекте, это решение не убьет сервер, если в таблицах например будет куча данных и куча обращений по этим запросам?